# Setting title of a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, title

I have a `UITabBarController` that sets 5 tabs that puts on screen an instance of `ViewController` in which i place the `UINavigationController`:

```
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:nc.view];
```

It works perfectly (the tabs and nav-bar), but there was a problem with setting title of a tab onto a bar.

I tried placing `self.title = @"something";` in `- (id)init` and `- (void)viewDidLoad` - first one did nothing, second changed my title of a tab, not navigation bar.

My question is: where to put my code, or what change should i make?

Comment: Since you asked about where to write code; I'll mention this: If you are getting your ViewControllers from a storyboard, `init` is never called at runtime. Technically, at runtime you are un-archiving a view controller that has already been initialized (when you built your app). The closest you get to init is `awakeFromNib`. Cheers!

Comment: The point is that i want to do this without interface builder/storyboard. Tried `awakeFromNib`, and even `viewDidAppear`, and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `UIViewController`, do this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"your title";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a really long trip to solve this tabbar-navigationbar issue, and finally found a complete explanation video. My problem was not setting title itself, it was about how to split views in right order.

Hierarchy that runs well:

- view with `UITabBarController`

  - view with `UINavigationController`

    - view with anything between tab and navigation bars

Then even setting `self.title` in third one makes it work. Nevertheless to differ tabbar title and navBar title You need to make it the way @looyao said.

[full step-by-step video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw) (code may be outdated - 2009, but explanation makes it still valuable)